# wso2 EMM iOS Server

Tags: javascript, java, ios, wso2, wso2-iot

So I'm new to WSO2 EMM but I have literally tried EVERYTHING I possibly know.

I've followed all the MDM certificate documents. I have an enterprise account.

I generated a CSR, uploaded to apple and downloaded my mdm.cer then converted it to mdm.pfx to upload to wso2 emm.

When I go to enroll my iPhone, when i Click download root certificate I get 500: Something has gone wrong

In the console I get the following error:

```
[2015-09-09 15:04:57,738] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.service.iOSMobilityManagerService] is not a function, it is object. (/emm/modules/iosemm.js#13) (/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag#2)
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.service.iOSMobilityManagerService] is not a function, it is object. (/emm/modules/iosemm.js#13) (/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag#2)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:447)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.interceptor.valve.APIManagerInterceptorValve.invoke(APIManagerInterceptorValve.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.service.iOSMobilityManagerService] is not a function, it is object. (/emm/modules/iosemm.js#13) (/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag#2)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c0._c_script_0(/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag:2)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c0.call(/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c0.call(/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.ios_utils.c0.exec(/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        ... 73 more
Caused by: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.service.iOSMobilityManagerService] is not a function, it is object. (/emm/modules/iosemm.js#13)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.executeScript(WebAppManager.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.require(WebAppManager.java:323)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        ... 82 more
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.service.iOSMobilityManagerService] is not a function, it is object. (/emm/modules/iosemm.js#13)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3712)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3767)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3755)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.newObject(ScriptRuntime.java:2346)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c20._c_anonymous_1(/emm/modules/iosemm.js:13)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c20.call(/emm/modules/iosemm.js)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c20._c_script_0(/emm/modules/iosemm.js:1)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c20.call(/emm/modules/iosemm.js)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm.modules.c20.exec(/emm/modules/iosemm.js)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        ... 89 more
```

Any help would be appreciated please!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit your `CSR` file to `WSO2` and request `WSO2` to sign your `CSR` file and get the signed `CSR` file in .plist format. Otherwise you cannot continue since it needs to be signed by an `MDM` vendor.
Please follow the 2nd step of following documentation

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM100/Generating+a+MDM+APNS+Certificate